# quantmod R- not using list of stocks

Tags: r, http-status-code-404, lapply, quantmod

I have a data frame with a column with the list of stocks.

```
paraCot$sigla

 [1] "AEN.BA"   "AGRO.BA"  "ALUA.BA"  "AUSO.BA"  "BHIP.BA"  "BMA.BA"   "BOLT.BA"  "BPAT.BA" 
 [9] "BRIO.BA"  "CADO.BA"  "CAPU.BA"  "CAPX.BA"  "CARC.BA"  "CECO2.BA"
```

and so on.
I want to download the prices for each one. I tried quantmod package.

```
Symbols=paste(shQuote(paraCot$sigla, type='cmd'), collapse=',')

Stocks = lapply(Symbols, 
                function(sym) {  na.omit(getSymbols(sym, from='2015-07-01', auto.assign=FALSE))
})
```

But I get an error.

> ...download failed after two attempts. Error message: HTTP error 404.

I tried introducing a list and using the same function and it works.

```
l=c("GAL", "AGRO.BA")
Stocks = lapply(l, 
                function(sym) {  na.omit(getSymbols(sym, from='2015-07-01', auto.assign=FALSE))
                })
```

I guess this is related to the type of data that is Symbols, but I see a list split by comma and each element enclosed by quotations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tickers <- paraCot$sigla
getSymbols(tickers, src = ‘yahoo’)
```

Make sure you have the latest `quantmod’ package installed. ( src = ‘google’ gives you an download error as they use different symbols or don’t have the data)

Comment: I have the latest version. 0.4-10, and still get the error message: "Error in curl::curl_download(cu, tmp, handle = h) : 
  Couldn't connect to server"